# How can I keep a blog post counter on PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, content-management-system

Is there a good way to keep track of page views for blog posts on a CMS on PHP?

For instance would I track sessions? Or Would I track Unique page views, etc. How would I check add that to each page without using google analytics if there is a robust library that is simple to use in either javascript, etc.

Comment: Nothing is going to be simpler and as maintenance free than using google analytics

Comment: What cms? Many already have basic page view statistics built in outside of google analytics. But it would make far more sense just to use google analytics

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at $_SERVER at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

You can grab a clients IP address using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and use a cookie or session to make sure you only store the "visit" once per unique IP address.

Your counter would simply be a PHP query that did a count of all DISTINCT IP addresses found in your table.